# JPA doesn't fetch the updated data

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am facing a very weird issue in JPA entity manager. I have tow Entities
1) Incident
2) Country

Country is master and Incident is child with ManyToOne.

Incident.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Incident")
public class Incident {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "incidentID")
    private Integer incidentID;

    @Column(name = "incidentTitle")
    private String incidentTitle;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "countryID")
    private Country country;

    @Transient
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "countryID")
    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    // Getter and setters


}
```

Country.Java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Country")
public class Country {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Incident> incident;


     @OneToMany
        @JoinColumn(
            name="countryID",nullable=false)
    public List<Incident> getIncident() {
        return incident;
    }

    public void setIncident(List<Incident> incident) {
        this.incident = incident;
    }
    //getter and setter

}
```

RepositoryImpl.java

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class IncidentRepositoryImpl implements IncidentRepository{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory sf) {
        this.em = sf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Override
    public Incident addIncident(Incident incident) {
        try {           
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(incident);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            return incident;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {            
            return null;
        }
    }


    public Incident findById(int id) {
        Incident incident = null;
        incident = (Incident) em.find(Incident.class, id);      
        return incident;

    }

}
```

When i add Incident, incident added successfully with countryID in Incident table, But when i try to fetch the same incident, country name comes null. But when i take restart of server or redeploy the application country name also comes. Hope there is cache issue with JAP entity manager. I try to use em.refresh(incident) in findById method, then country name comes successfully. But this refresh method is very expensive call.

Please suggest some alternate solution, how to update jpa cache automatically.

Comment: Sounds like your transaction manager failed to commit the insert and flush the session.

Comment: So, what is the mistake that i did. Can you please let me know ?

Comment: What are you mapping the country field **and** the getter? The latter with @Transient. Remove all the annotations from the getter.

Answer (score 0):

On your `EntityManager em`, add

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
private EntityManager em;
```

With `PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION`, Spring takes control of the life cycle of `EntityManager`

Comment: Have tried your suggestion, but didn't resolve the issue.